AWSlocal Error: 500 when calling aws sqs queue through localstack - (reached max retries: 4)
I am new to Docker and AWS, but trying do a small project.
Aim is to get data from AWS SQS queue through localstack, make a few transformations in local machine and store it in Postgres database. I am stuck on the first step of receiving data from AWS SQS Queue.
I setup my docker, pulled the images of localstack and postgres by the docker-compose.yml file.
Technically, I should be able to access my aws queue, and receive messages from it. But, I believe I am missing some really simple configuration step or setup. Help!
VERSIONS:
aws-cli/1.33.13 Python/3.10.11 Windows/10 botocore/1.34.131
docker --version
Docker version 26.1.4, build 5650f9b
docker-compose --version
Docker Compose version v2.27.1-desktop.1
I started the docker by "docker-compose up -d" and checked the status by "docker-compose ps".
Name and image,
localstack-1,   docker/localstack   and
postgres-1,     docker/postgres
So, technically, this means the docker has pulled the localstack image, which has my queue (or so I understand).
awslocal sqs list-queues
An error occurred (500) when calling the ListQueues operation (reached max retries: 4):
I am lost and I am sure the answer is a clearly obvious result, but braincells have left me.
I tried to create a new queue, 
**awslocal sqs create-queue --queue-name localstack-queue**

An error occurred (500) when calling the CreateQueue operation (reached max retries: 4):

**aws configure list**

      Name                    Value             Type    Location
      ----                    -----             ----    --------
   profile                <not set>             None    None
access_key     ****************test shared-credentials-file
secret_key     ****************test shared-credentials-file
    region                us-east-1      config-file    ~/.aws/config

~~~~
I tried to check the logs of localstack, by 
**docker-compose logs localstack**  (Can't understand the issues in the logs )

docker-compose.yml: `version` is obsolete"
localstack-1  | Waiting for all LocalStack services to be ready
localstack-1  | 2024-06-22 16:32:31,754 CRIT Supervisor is running as root.  Privileges were not dropped because no user is specified in the config file.  If you intend to run as root, you can set user=root in the config file to avoid this message.
localstack-1  | 2024-06-22 16:32:31,764 INFO supervisord started with pid 15
localstack-1  | 2024-06-22 16:32:32,768 INFO spawned: 'infra' with pid 20
localstack-1  | 2024-06-22 16:32:33,771 INFO success: infra entered RUNNING state, process localstack-1  | 2024-06-22T16:32:36.098:INFO:hypercorn.error: Running on localstack-1  |
localstack-1  | 2024-06-22T16:33:54.059:WARNING:localstack.utils.server.http2_server: Error in proxy handler for request POST http://localhost:4566/: Operation detection failed. Missing Action in request for query-protocol service ServiceModel(sqs). 
.
.
.
localstack-1  |     raise ProtocolParserError(
localstack-1  | localstack.aws.protocol.parser.ProtocolParserError: Operation detection failed. Missing Action in request for query-protocol service ServiceModel(sqs).

The logs of my postgres is stable and ready for connections. 

Docker-compose.yml file: 
version: "3.9"
services:
  localstack:
    image: docker/localstack
    ports:
      - "4566:4566"
  postgres:
    image: docker/postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres



hi Sirius,
from the sample you provided, it seems like you are not using our recommended localstack image, the correct tag is localstack/localstack.
Please see our documentation on how to setup localstack using docker-compose here:

Localstack version 3 works fine
here is the code
PS C:\Windows\system32> aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 sqs create-queue --queue-name localstack-queue --region us-east-1 
{
        "QueueUrl": "http://sqs.us-east-1.localhost.localstack.cloud:4566/000000000000/localstack-queue" 
}

